# Exclude nuget package versions in VS2015 during package restore

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget

Is there a way to not include the nuget version of a package in the package folder after restoration? I am trying to add link references to content in the package, but these break on a nuget update. My build server (TC) has an option to pass the -ExcludeVersion to nuget.exe, how can I do this with VS2015?